# Python Ctypes module: symbol lookup error for gpiod library when running C code

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a python script to call C code. This C code is dependent on the gpiod library. I have reviewed and tried other solutions I have seen on stackoverflow, but they are not asking the same problem. When I run my function I get a symbol lookup error:

```
python3: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmylib.so: undefined symbol: gpiod_chip_open
```

Starting with python code I initialize my shared lib and call the desired C function (I have also tried initializing with the 'os.RTLD_GLOBAL' mode as well):

```
def hw_init():
    lsx1262 = CDLL("/usr/lib/libmylib.so", mode=os.RTLD_LAZY)
    lsx1262.python_hello_world()  # (works)
    lsx1262.python_sx1262_init()
```

I compile my C .so file with:

```
g++ $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) -fpic -lgpiod -c $(C_SRC_FILES)
```

When I run `nm -D /usr/lib/my_custom_lib.so` I get the following output:

```
         U fwrite@GLIBC_2.4
         w __gmon_start__
         U gpiod_chip_close
         U gpiod_chip_get_line
         U gpiod_chip_open
         U gpiod_line_event_get_fd
         U gpiod_line_event_read
         U gpiod_line_event_wait
         U gpiod_line_event_wait_bulk
```

As you can see, when I compile my shared library, I link it to the -lgpiod library. And the functions are modules available in my .so file. I am not sure what I am missing here to get my C code to run the gpiod dependency.

I am expecting the C code to see the gpiod library, but this error indicates that python is trying to find the gpiod library. Thank you.

Comment: To get your question reopened, explain why/how your question is different, rather than just asserting that it is.